# Feed Inception with OpenCV image

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, tensorflow

Currently I'm feeding the test for Inception v3 with:

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

But instead I need to crop the image before feeding it to the CNN, so I'm using imread and cropping the matrix.
But if I do it I can't use it as image_data since it is expecting a jpeg binary.

Comment: A quick fix should be: crop your mat, save it in jpeg in a temporary folder and read the new image. I don't know tensorflow but I think it should be possible to read directly a decoded image from memory.

Comment: That's what I did as a quick fix but it is missing the whole point of using the tensorFlow with GPU by having many images written to the HD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using PIL instead of OpenCV.
It is possible to feed it directly and also the drawing function seems better than the one I was using for OpenCV.

```
img = Image.open(tstImg)
image = img.resize((1936, 1296), Image.ANTIALIAS)
crop_img = image.crop((x, y, x+x_adds, y+y_adds))
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': crop_img})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': cv2.imencode('.jpg', image_data)[1].tostring()})
```